# How to convert array of numbers into a date string format. Typescript/Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to parse an `array` of numbers to a date string in `typescript`?

This is how I would do it in C#:

```
    int[] date = { 2017, 10, 20 };

    public string convert(dynamic date)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", date[1], date[2], date[0]);
    }
```

Any suggestions to do this in `typescript`/`javascript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most similar to your C# code would probably be something like:

```
const date = [2017, 10, 20];

convert(date: number[]): string {
  return `${date[0]}/${date[1]}/${date[2]}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
let date = [2017, 10, 20]
const convert = function(d){
  return d.join('/')
}
```

or, for more versatile solutions you should check the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) built-in object.